# How to generate JSON examples from OpenAPI 3.0 yaml file?

Tags: java, json, yaml, swagger, openapi

I have my openapi: 3.0.0 YAML file, I'm looking for a way to generate test data response (JSON object) from schema.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133923/3587260) is what I am looking for, but I can't get it working for openapi: 3.0.0, the code works perfectly for "swagger": "2.0" definitions.
I have tried to get the code working with Swagger Java libraries 2.x, which support OpenAPI 3.0. I know I need to use version 2.x of Swagger.

```
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser;
import io.swagger.models.*;
import io.swagger.inflector.examples.*;
import io.swagger.inflector.examples.models.Example;
import io.swagger.inflector.processors.JsonNodeExampleSerializer;
import io.swagger.util.Json;
import io.swagger.util.Yaml;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;


// Load your OpenAPI/Swagger definition
Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read("http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json");

// Create an Example object for the Pet model
Map<String, Model> definitions = swagger.getDefinitions();
Model pet = definitions.get("Pet");
Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromModel("Pet", pet, definitions, new HashSet<String>());
// Another way:
// Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromProperty(new RefProperty("Pet"), swagger.getDefinitions());

// Configure example serializers
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);

// Convert the Example object to string

// JSON example
String jsonExample = Json.pretty(example);
System.out.println(jsonExample);
```

This code is working, just need to get the same code working for openapi: 3.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution,

```
OpenAPI swagger = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("url to Open API 3.0 Swagger")
Map < String, Schema > definitions = swagger.getComponents().getSchemas()
Schema model = definitions.get("Pet")
Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromSchema(model, definitions)
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer())
Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule)
String jsonExample = Json.pretty(example);
System.out.println(jsonExample);
```

Comment: Hi, Can you add the imports used here as well ?

Answer (score 8):

```
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.models.Example;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.ExampleBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.processors.JsonNodeExampleSerializer;
import io.swagger.util.Json;

OpenAPI swagger = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Downloads\\Petstore-1.0.yaml")
Map<String, Schema> definitions = swagger.getComponents().getSchemas();
Schema model = definitions.get("Pet");
Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromSchema(model, definitions);
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
String jsonExample = Json.pretty(example);
System.out.println(jsonExample);
```

Dependency for swagger inflector

```
compile group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-inflector', version: '2.0.0'
```