# How can I dynamically connect to a Swagger / OpenAPI endpoint in java?

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, openapi

I want to write code that dynamically connects to an OpenAPI endpoint. I don't want to use code generation.

Something like so:

```java
OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation(...).getOpenAPI();
String path = ...;
String method = "get";
Map<String, String> parameters = ...;

Operation operation = openAPI.get(path).readOperationsMap().get(method);

//What do I do next?!
WebTaget target = WhatGoesHere(path, parametrs);
Response response = target.request()...;
```

There must be a library out there that can take an `OpenAPI` definition and make connections right?

Comment: I'm not aware of any dynamic Java clients for OpenAPI. But there's a library that can [generate JSON examples for request bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978052/113116) based on their schema definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This is for clojure but has a java class to hook into: https://github.com/oliyh/martian#java