# How to generate json input from openapi yaml schema

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-editor

I have Open API yaml schema from which I want to generate input json.
Is there any utility to generate inputs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate JSON examples from OpenAPI 3.0 yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978052/how-to-generate-json-examples-from-openapi-3-0-yaml-file)

Comment: It doesn't work if two object have same child object/schema. First child object gets populated but consecutive objects empty json is getting populated .

It also not work if schema is scattered in multiple files