# Getting sample request body json of rest endpoint using swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

we have a spring boot microservice with swagger v3. I need to build a sample request payload json with dummy values for each path in api docs (exactly how the swagger-ui builds a example value payload for each endpoint) . Is there any api provided by swagger to get the example payload directly ?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to generate JSON examples from OpenAPI/Swagger model definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41408768/113116), [How to generate JSON examples from OpenAPI 3.0 YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978052/113116)?

Comment: If you have filled your openapi.yaml with `example` values swagger ui will show the request with you example values.

You can also import your yaml in postman and it will generate example requests based on the same values.

Comment: @Helen This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks. Does similar library exists in javascript as well ?

Comment: @DavidDecanio [openapi-sampler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-sampler)