# I want to create curl request from given swagger.json?

Tags: swagger, code-generation, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am looking for a solution to extract api request from swagger.json in curl,GO,Node.js in java!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In other words, what do you need the request data for? We'd need to understand your problem more clearly to suggest a workable solution.

Comment: I am trying to create codegens, like postman has but in java

Comment: So something like https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet but using OpenAPI instead of HAR as a source?

Comment: The [Swagger Inflector](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector) library can [generate JSON payload examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41408768/113116) based on an OpenAPI schema. But that's just the request body. As for the full HTTP request, I suggest you review the code of existing codegen projects such as [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to see how they handle this.

Comment: You'll probably have to use [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/) to parse the OpenAPI file and extract various info (endpoint paths, parameters, etc.) that could then be converted into curl options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is useful, but I had a similar problem recently and created a tool called [cURL Request Generator](https://github.com/christianhelle/curlgenerator). It's written in C# using .NET 8.0 and I use it to generate Powershell scripts that represent each OpenAPI operation

Using it against the [Swagger Petstore v3](https://petstore3.swagger.io/) example produces the following files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  593 Dec 10 10:44 DeleteOrder.ps1        
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  231 Dec 10 10:44 DeletePet.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  358 Dec 10 10:44 DeleteUser.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  432 Dec 10 10:44 GetFindPetsByStatus.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  504 Dec 10 10:44 GetFindPetsByTags.ps1  
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  371 Dec 10 10:44 GetInventory.ps1       
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  247 Dec 10 10:44 GetLoginUser.ps1       
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  291 Dec 10 10:44 GetLogoutUser.ps1      
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  540 Dec 10 10:44 GetOrderById.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  275 Dec 10 10:44 GetPetById.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  245 Dec 10 10:44 GetUserByName.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  513 Dec 10 10:44 PostAddPet.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  521 Dec 10 10:44 PostCreateUser.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  610 Dec 10 10:44 PostCreateUsersWithListInput.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  464 Dec 10 10:44 PostPlaceOrder.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  299 Dec 10 10:44 PostUpdatePetWithForm.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  274 Dec 10 10:44 PostUploadFile.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  513 Dec 10 10:44 PutUpdatePet.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 christian 197121  541 Dec 10 10:44 PutUpdateUser.ps1
```

A POST request would look something like:

```
<#
  Request: POST /pet
  Summary: Add a new pet to the store
  Description: Add a new pet to the store
#>

curl -X POST https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet `
  -H 'Accept: application/json' `
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
  -d '{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "name",
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "name"
  },
  "photoUrls": [
    ""
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "name"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}'
```

and a GET request would look something like:

```
<#
  Request: GET /pet/{petId}
  Summary: Find pet by ID
  Description: Returns a single pet
#>
param(
   <# ID of pet to return #>
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [String] $petId
)

curl -X GET https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet/$petId `
  -H 'Accept: application/json' `
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```