# ServiceStack OpenAPI and Postman: Get the request 'Example value' in the output to import into Postman

Tags: postman, servicestack, swagger-ui, openapi

Is there a way to get ServiceStacks PostmanFeature to also export the 'Example value', that can be seen in the Swagger-UI, so that when I use Postman to import the spec, I also get the example value in the "raw body" in Postman?

So, I would like this 'Example value':

[image]

to be present here in Postman, after import:

[image]

Today, after import, I get it to list it as "form-data", which is not what I want:

[image]

*EDIT*

I also noticed that the "Description" column in "Params" is empty, even though I have used attributes to describe it:

[image]

and

[image]

Am I doing it wrong, or is there a way?

Comment: There are tools and libraries such as [`openapi-sampler`](https://github.com/Redocly/openapi-sampler), [Swagger Inflector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133923/113116) and others that can generate JSON examples based on an OpenAPI Schema definition.

Comment: Thanks Helen, could be good tools to use. I was hoping that there was a way in ServiceStack to do it, so that the plugin exports a full and ready to use collection in Postman.